# Angular - Communicating through a component does not work on the production build

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, subject

I am working on an Angular application where i implemented the functionality of sending messages to different components using a service.Everything works great on dev mode but on the production build the service does not send the message.Below are the steps that i did to implement this functionality.

First of all, i created a a service where i created an observable(subject) object.Every component will subscribe to this observable and the service will have a method used to send messages.

```
@Injectable()
export class ComponentMessageService  {

    /** message subject */
    private messageSource = new Subject<MyMessage>();

    /** message observable */
    messageSource$ = this.messageSource.asObservable();

    /** broadcastMessage */
    broadcastMessage(message: MyMessage) {
        this.messageSource.next(message);
    }
}
```

Next i have created a component that will define the generic way to subscribe to the service.Every component will extend this class.

```
export abstract class MessagingComponent{

    disposableObject:any;

    constructor(public componentMessageService:ComponentMessageService){
        this.disposableObject=componentMessageService.messageSource$.subscribe(message => {
                this.handleMessage(message);
        });
    }

    handleMessage(message: MyMessage){

    }

    unsubscribeMethod(){
        this.disposableObject.unsubscribe():
    }
}
```

The final step was creating an actual object and overriding the handleMessage function.When the message is caught by this component i want to change a variable to display a popup.

```
export class InstructionsPopupComponent extends MessagingComponent{

    constructor(public componentMessageService:ComponentMessageService,
                private changeDetector : ChangeDetectorRef){
        super(componentMessageService);
    }

    handleMessage(message: MyMessage){
        if(message.messageType==MyMessageTypes.DISPLAY){
            this.display=true;
            this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
        }
    }

    ngOnDestroy(){
        this.changeDetector.detach();
        this.unsubscribeMethod();
    }
}
```

To send the message i import the service and then call the broadcastMessage.
The application i am working on was build from an Jhipster app.

Comment: It is very strange that this works on dev but not on prod. Any error or warning is thrown to the console after running build?

Comment: The build seems fine.From what i can see when i click the button that launches the message everything works fine until it reaches the this.messageSource.next(message); line in the "broadcastMessage" method.